# Asynchronous data loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am downloading data from the API and writing to `state` `(posts)`

Condition after `let res = await response.json();` will be done earlier than this function

At what point should he perform `this.setState({posts: res})`?

At the moment it is inappropriate because:

- I am getting a large object from the bugs with nested lists of objects
- to call `render()` an object must already exist in `state`
- I can not define an empty object in the `state` because it is too complicated

Function:

```
async loadData()
{
    try
    {
        this.setState({ loading: true});

        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        let res = await response.json();

        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)
        {
            console.log(res);

            this.setState({ posts: res});
            this.setState({ loading: false});
        }
        else
        {
            let error = res;
            throw error;
        }

    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.log('error' + error)
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `render(){ if(!this.state.posts) return null; /*...*/ }`

Comment: Wow, here is a piece of code that would look a lot better without async / await, there are just promises, why not threat them as such? No need for the akward error handling, a bit of separation in the code

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. "to call render() an object must already exist in state". You can allow render to be called (and you should never call it manually) whenever the component is displayed or its data changes. You just need to design the component so it renders something sensible if the data you want to display is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

Just use promises

```
loadData() {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  });

  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(res => {
    this.setState({
      posts: res
    });
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log('error ' + reason);
  }).finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why the second `catch`? What would go wrong with the json parsing? Shouldn't the `loading` flag be handled after the second `catch`, considering this should probably always be set back to false? Why not do them in one go as part of the `setState` handling? Also, a bit more info as to why you are suggesting him promises (async/await does mostly the same in the end)?

Comment: What if it is incorrect json? Then we will catch it.
About state - yeah you are right, so I added finally block.
Yes, async/await does the same thing, but promises much more comfortable to use.

Comment: That would not be necessary, if you would actually return the `response.json()` block, as you can see from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75xwc3tk/2/). So in that case I would probably catch the reason, and return an empty array from there, so that in the finally you can set both the `posts` state and the `loading` flag in 1 statement ;) Would save you quite some statements as well

Comment: @Icepickle Yeah, you are absolutely right, there is no need in inner then/catch/finally blocks if we will return promise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use `async`/`await` in your current example. I guess you believe that by using await, your component will only be rendered when the full `loadData` function is through, but that is incorrect, as `async` implies a promise will be returned.

Another assumption your are making, that you cannot `render` anything as long as your data wasn't added to your state yet (you mention call render, but this gets called through react itself, so you don't need to worry about it, as it is part of the [component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle))

I created a small sample of how loading data can be done, based on your code with as much comments as I can think of ;)

```js
const { Component } = React;

// only shows the breeds and potential subbreeds
const Breed = ({ name, subBreeds }) => {
  return (
    <div className="breed-item">
      <span className="breed-title">{ name }</span>
      { subBreeds && subBreeds.map( (sub, i) => <Breed key={i} name={sub} /> ) }
    </div>
  );
};

class BreedContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // i'll be loading from the start
    this.state = { loading: true };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // flag to make sure I don't update my state when I am no longer mounted
    this.mounted = true;
    // get's called when my component will be added to the dom
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      // return the json
      .then( response => response.json() )
      // error occured with parsing the json, handle it
      // through the console, and return an empty object
      .catch( error => console.error( error ) || {} )
      // set the state (in case still mounted)
      .then( result => this.mounted && this.setState({
        loading: false,
        breeds: result.message
      }) );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // unmounted, make sure I do not update the state after that
    this.mounted = false;
  }
  render() {
    const { breeds, loading } = this.state;
    // loading, so just display a loading message
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading please wait</div>;
    }
    // no breeds available, an error might have occured
    // the user would have to check the console to make sure
    // or you could save the error message instead
    if (!breeds) {
      return <div>No dog breeds found</div>;
    }
    // show all the retrieved breeds
    return (
      <div className="breed-container">
        { Object.keys( breeds ).map( (breed, i) => <Breed name={breed} subBreeds={breeds[breed]} key={i} /> ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <BreedContainer />, target );
```

```css
.breed-item {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  padding: 5px;
}
.breed-item > .breed-item {
  border-left: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.breed-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```